# DAO Connection throws ISAM Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dao, ms-access-2000

I can connect to an access database via ADO w/o issue, but if I attempt to connect using a DAO connection it throws the error of `Could not find installable ISAM`  I am  using VS2013 and it is communicating with Access 2000.  This is the syntax I am using (DAO) to connect to my database.  This syntax works with VS2010...

```
DAO.Database dd;
DAO.DBEngine db = new DAO.DBEngine()
DAO.TableDef tdf1;
string sourceTable = "dbo.Master";
string linkedTable = "Master";
string database = "C:\\Test.mdb;"
string sqlconnection = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL SERVER; SERVER=TinyOne;Database=InterWebDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes";

dd.OpenDatabase(database);
tdf1.dd.CreateTableDef(linkedTable);
tdf1.Connect = sqlconnection;
tdf1.SourceTableName = sourcetable;
//The below line produces the ISAM error
dd.TableDefs.Append(tdf1);
```

Comment: Have you created a link with those same properties inside an Access session?

Comment: @HansUp - yes, I have.